# How to read all characters in tessract(JTessBoxEdit.NET)

Tags: tesseract

Trying to read all characters A to Z but I and J letters coming as U. Attaching input and output in below.pls help me

input

[image]

output

[image]

Trained Data
  [image]

Comment: Works fine on my end, which traineddata do you use?

Comment: Above In console I,J comming as U how can i solve thsat problem ..

Comment: Both 'I' and 'j' in trained data arevery different compared to test image one (looks like j is in lowercase and I has different font), S-Z and t-z are missing in traineddata. Have you tried (eng.traineddata from here)[https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best]?

Comment: yes i tried eng.traineddata there it is coming correctly.But what i generated (eg: spcSymbols.traineddata) it is not reading properly (I, J)

Comment: How to merge two files(eng.traineddata, spcSymb.traineddata).please help me...  @Dmitrii

Comment: You can't merge those files. If you want to add specific font to eng.traineddata - you need to train from scratch using [langdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata). It is unclear for me why did you change font in your trained data (which is obvious if one would look at current and past posted image).